# How do you get text from a field in one view controller to another? Always getting (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a text field that you can fill out in one view controller, and I want to press a button in another view controller and it adds something on to the end of that field. So currently I have:

CSExtracts.m

```
-(IBAction)savedataExtract:(id)sender{
    NSString *savestringExtract = fieldExtract.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestringExtract forKey:@"savedstringExtract"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
-(IBAction)loaddataExtract:(id)sender{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstringExtract = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstringExtract"];
    [fieldExtract setText:loadstringExtract];
    [label setText:loadstringExtract];

}

-(IBAction)KeyboardResponder{
    [fieldExtract resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstringExtract"];
    [fieldExtract setText:loadstring3];
    [label setText:loadstring3];

}
```

This basically allows me to type in a text box and save it and load it. I have a button in a CSViewController that when pressed is supposed to add a line to the end of this:

CSViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)addInt:(id)sender{
    CSExtracts *viewA = [[CSExtracts alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];
    NSString *textfieldtext = viewA->fieldExtract.text;

    NSString *intvar = @"int varName;";
    //NSString *currentStr = fieldExtract.text;
    NSString *savestringExtract = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",textfieldtext, intvar];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestringExtract forKey:@"savedstringExtract"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

This works in that it changes the text in the field, however, the variable textfieldtext which is supposed to be the current value of the text field is always set to null. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no text in the text field because **viewDidLoad** has not been called on the instance of CSExtracts controller before you try get the text value so it could not be loaded from NSUserDefaults.

```
CSExtracts *viewA = [[CSExtracts alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];
//at this point viewDidLoad has not been called so textfieldtext = null
NSString *textfieldtext = viewA->fieldExtract.text;
```

You can try adding a property to your CSExtracts controller

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fieldExtractText;
```

and then in initWithNibName:bundle:

```
- (id) initWithNibName: (NSString*) name bundle: (NSString*) bundleName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: name bundle: bundleName];
    if(self){
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        self.fieldExtractText = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedstringExtract"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In CSViewController:

```
- (IBAction) addInt: (id) sender
{
    CSExtracts *viewA = [[CSExtracts alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];
    NSString *textfieldtext = viewA.fieldExtractText;
    ...
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about making sure viewDidLoad is called first? Sorry, very new to this

Comment: viewDidLoad is called after a controller's view has been loaded. This happens when you access the view property of your view controller, fx. viewA.view - after this line viewDidLoad has been called. Usually it is not a good idea to call getters (fx viewA.view) for side effects (loading of the view).

Comment: Adding this line resulted resulted in
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/samwong/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/44D48320-69CE-4A38-A7C2-5E2B819544C0/Code Snippets.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewA''
when the button is pressed. Also the error property access result unused - getter should not be used for side effects - on that line

Comment: Ok. I think the best idea for you would be to add a property to your CSExtracts controller fx fieldExtractText and assign to it the value loaded from NSUserDefaults. You can do this in initWithNibName:bundle: of your CSExtracts class. Then in addInt:, instead of accessing the text field, access that property.